# Ruby minitest uninitialized constant ::ActiveSupport (NameError)

Tags: ruby, minitest

I've got pure Ruby class which does the parsing of the JSON file to the expected hash (located in `src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz.rb`). I want to test this class with Minitest like below:

```
# test/src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz_test.rb

require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative '../../../../src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz'

module Parsers
  module IncomingEvents
    class CreateQuiz < ActiveSupport::TestCase

      test 'parse JSON to expected format' do
        assert_equal expected_hash, service.call
      end

      private

      def service
        @service ||= ::Parsers::IncomingEvents::CreateQuiz.new(payload: payload)
      end

      def payload
        {
          'quiz' =>
          {
            'first_name' => 'john',
            'last_name' => 'doe',
            'ssn' => '1234',
          }
        }.to_json
      end

      def expected_hash
        { 'name': 'john doe' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I'm trying to run above code via `ruby test/src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz_test.rb` I'm getting below error:

```
test/src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz_test.rb:11:in `<module:IncomingEvents>': uninitialized constant Parsers::IncomingEvents::ActiveSupport (NameError)
    from test/src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz_test.rb:10:in `<module:Parsers>'
    from test/src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz_test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Well, you don't seem to be loading activesupport here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's true - I should have `require 'active_support'` at the bottom. Surprising that it's not part of Minitest itself. Thanks!

Comment: I would be **very** surprised if it _was_ a part of minitest. activesupport is a fat dependency, not to be included on a whim or because you need one or two methods from it. In your particular case, do you _need_ activesupport's version of TestCase or can you use the one from minitest? https://ruby-doc.com/stdlib-trunk/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html

Comment: @SergioTulentsev gets an error: `test/src/parsers/incoming_events/create_quiz_test.rb:11:in test': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)` If I use `Minitest::Test` instead of `ActiveSupport::TestCase`.